# CSRF error when using a cached response

Tags: django, django-cache, django-caching

I am doing some aggressive caching and this results in a CSRF error when I use a previously cached old response.

Is there a way to just refresh the csrf token inside the cached response?

Unable to understand the Caching section in 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/

Can someone elaborate a bit on this?

I am using a database backend cache and am using cache.get(key) and cache.set(key, value) to store and retrieve the response.

Comment: Can you put some code to knw how you implemented caching.

Comment: have added the cache related details

Comment: Current csrf value is stored in a `csrftoken` cookie, you can read it from there during every request and update.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use the csrf_protect decorator to refresh the CSRF tokens in the cached response.